# Chart Series to Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, charts, series, points

I'm using VB.NET 2010
how to get all data from series on a chart into an array or a `textbox` or a `table`?

I'm using this code to plot the graph:

```
serie1.Points.AddXY(Val(Label4.Text), Val(Label5.Text))
```

I just need to read that values from the `serie1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the values in a list while you are adding it to the series or if you really want to access it after adding to the series you could do the following.

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
DataPoint[] arr = series.Points.ToArray<DataPoint>();
```

or

```
List<DataPoint> lst = series.Points.ToList<DataPoint>();
```

and then you can access the `X` and `Y` values using a `foreach` loop

```
foreach(var pt in lst)
{
   pt.XValue  // access Xvalue like this
   pt.YValue  // access Yvalue like this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to get the values from the first series you can use these lines of codes:

```
Dim anArray(Chart1(0).Points.Count) As Double
For i = 0 To Chart1.Series(0).Points.Count -1
    anArray(i)=Chart1.Series(0).Points(i).Y
Next
```